# Windows service and sharepoint 2007 workflows

Tags: 2007, workflow

I have a custom windows service, which supposed to check expired workflow tasks and send them back to the originator (run new workflow) plus then cancels the originator`s expired workflow completely.

My problem is how I reference BIN directory DLLs in windows service? 
I have all my worfklow interfaces there...

I GACed those interfaces there and tried again...it went further...

No it throws that it cant find workflow DLLs:

```
07/27/2010 11:25:10.92  CheckerService.exe (0x12F4) 0x1400  Windows SharePoint Services     Workflow Infrastructure         75yn    Unexpected  Load Workflow Assembly: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CaseWF, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d3e9de178cbaba7a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  File name: 'CaseWF, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d3e9de178cbaba7a'     at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)     at System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)     at System.Ref...
```

How can I correctly reference or got this to work? 
Thanks before hand

Comment: CaseWF.dll is in the GAC also...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why wouldn't you write this as a SharePoint feature and timer job?  Access to the objects is cleaner and status, error reporting, and management are integrated into the CA interface.

Comment: Great point :D Never cross my mind:P That`s what I need to do asap.